# keeping the GUI responsive and interactive in WPF when running methods in other classes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-interface

I am writing VB.Net (.net framework 4.5) WPF software that has a class that is constantly reading data over a network, then populating a listbox on the WPF GUI as data comes in. Users can meanwhile click on a listboxitem to see more information about it in a separate textblock.

My question is, how do I keep the GUI responsive and useable while also doing this other stuff (in a different class) in the background?

My thoughts so far:

1. Instantiate the GUI and the background classes at the same time when the application first runs (but then how do they interact?)
2. Using threading from within the GUI MainWindow - but then how do I get it to update the GUI, being a method in another class? Also, which threading code do I need? (It's my first time really trying to do this and I haven't done any code in vb.net before...)

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Here's some sample code:

```
'GUI Class
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ShowLoginScreen()
    'run background thread somehow?
End Sub
Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    'nicely stop the background thread
End Sub

'background class
Private stopRunningFlag As Boolean = False
Private dataList As List(Of DataType)
Sub StartRunning()
    Do Until stopRunningFlag.Equals(True)
        For Each data As DataTypeIn dataList
            'read and process data
            'update GUI
        Next
        'read more data in
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to use threads or ASYNC.

Comment: But nothing about your background class is in the background

Comment: yeah, sorry, my example wasn't clear - it's not reading from the GUI, but automatically checking an external data source for new data. And it does this continuously - the user doesn't have to press a button to make it happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Code was converted from C# to VB

Let's say we have a class containing stuff you want to send to the UI:

```
Public Class MyData
End Class
```

We can use the `SynchronisationContext` implemented by WPF to send a message to the UI thread when we want to update the UI. Note that the methods `Run` and `GetDataFromSomewhere` will not block the UI. Note that the class uses a `CancellationToken` to send the message to the background thread that it should stop what its doing when we close the application. The `BackgroundStuff` has an event that can be subscribed to to get notified when new data is available.

```
Public Class BackgroundStuff
    Private ReadOnly _context As SynchronizationContext
    Private _cts As New CancellationTokenSource()
    Public Sub New()
        'this constructor has to be called on the UI thread so
        'this class knows how to send a message to the UI thread.
        _context = SynchronizationContext.Current
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Run(_cts.Token))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Run(token As CancellationToken)
        While Not token.IsCancellationRequested
            Dim data As MyData = GetMyDataFromSomewhere()
            SendData(data)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMyDataFromSomewhere() As MyData
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        Return New MyData()
    End Function

    Public Event MyDataAdded As Action(Of MyData)

    Private Sub SendData(data As MyData)
        _context.Post(Function(o) 
        RaiseEvent MyDataAdded(DirectCast(o, MyData))

End Function, data)
    End Sub

    Public Sub [End]()
        _cts.Cancel()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And finally, some code in the `MainWindow` (I added a simple listbox to add the `MyData` elements).

```
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window
    Private ReadOnly _backgroundStuff As BackgroundStuff
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        _backgroundStuff = New BackgroundStuff()
        AddHandler _backgroundStuff.MyDataAdded, AddressOf _backgroundStuff_MyDataAdded
        AddHandler Me.Closing, AddressOf MainWindow_Closing
    End Sub

    Private Sub _backgroundStuff_MyDataAdded(obj As MyData)
        MyListBox.Items.Add(obj)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        _backgroundStuff.[End]()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this! I'm trying to implement it, and the "_context.Post(Function(o) 
        RaiseEvent MyDataAdded(DirectCast(o, MyData))" is giving me trouble - it says that _context should have 2 parameters - a SendingOrPostCallback, and a state Object. Can you explain these to me? I think there's a problem with your Function(o) call, but I don't understand it well enough to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out - took the liberty of editing your code to correct it. Basically some of the "Function" calls needed to be "Sub" calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual example of something that works:

```
Private Sub Whatever()
    Dispatcher.Invoke(New Action(Function() ListBox1.Items.Add("Hello")))

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Whatever)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not WPF but WinForms

Comment: I wrote the code for windows forms. Buttons and listboxes are available in both winforms and WPF. What would give you the impression this is WPF?

Comment: The question clearly states WPF, WPF does not have Control.Invoke, so this is not an answer

Comment: So you change it to dispatcher. My bad